# Optimize my own atoi

Tags: c

```
    int myAtoi2(char *str)
    {
        int number = 0;
        char *ptr = str;

        if ( *ptr == '-' ) {
          number = number - ( *++ptr - '0' );
          ptr++;
        }

        while ( isdigit ( *( ptr ) ) ){
          if ( number < 0 ) {
            number = number * 10 - (*ptr++ - '0');
          }
          else
            number = number * 10 + (*ptr++ - '0');
        }

       return number;
   }
```

Is there any way to make my own atoi better ( maybe clean code and better performance )?

Comment: Why does you function return an `int` if you don't handle negative numbers?

Comment: Yes, there are ways, but you should rather post to Code Review site since it's a working function.

Comment: Start with avoiding _magic numbers_!

Comment: @MaxZoom `sizeof(str)` would give the size of a pointer.  Were you thinking of `strlen()`?  Even then, he's counting consecutive digits from the start of the string, whereas `strlen()` would count everything up to the null char (even non-digits).

Comment: I agree that code review is a better community for this.

Comment: You'll want to put a bit more meat in your post if you're going to put this up on CR. Add a description of the problem you're solving *before* the code block, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be radically simplified like this. You only need to parse the string once, and maintain one value. This is for `unsigned` values. If you want negative numbers and range checking, that will add a bit more to the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

unsigned myOwnAtoi( char *str )
{
    unsigned number = 0;
    char *ptr = str;
    while(isdigit(*ptr)) {
        number = number * 10 + *ptr++ - '0';
    }
    return number;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("%u\n", myOwnAtoi("123456"));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
123456
```